# Unity: material has shiny white outline

Tags: unity, materials

I have two different projects open in Unity. But my grass material appears different in each project, despite all the parameters being the same.

See this image:
[image: Example of material inspector from each project, showing different results]

On the left is the desired appearance. But on the right my material has a strange white-ish outline. How do I get rid of it?

I have tried copying the material between the projects, and the problem seems to be independent of the available lighting

Comment: The usual advice here is to close Unity, delete your `Library` folder, then re-open your project. This forces Unity to re-generate its cached versions of all assets, and often fixes seemingly inexplicable bugs where the editor is doing something nonsensical. Try that with both projects, and see if the problem persists. Also double-check that both projects are using identical lighting and graphics quality settings, and that you haven't overridden the default shaders in either one.

Answer (score 1):

Try to re-import your assets and shaders. Like *DMGregory* mentioned in the comments, try deleting your Library.

Make sure the lighting effects are the same in both the projects.